# Unable to execute a command inside a docker container

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, go, sdk

I am trying to spin up a Postgres container via the Docker Go SDK. I can get the container started, and I copy my SQL file into the container and verified the file is there.

I cannot run this file, which right now just contains `CREATE TABLE tester;`

Here is my Go code that I am trying to use:

```
package gosqlcontainer

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func StartContainer() string {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    imageName := "postgres"

    out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)

    container, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: imageName, Env: []string{"POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"},
    }, nil, nil, nil, "")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, container.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    tarFile := TarFile("test.sql")
    if err = cli.CopyToContainer(ctx, container.ID, "/home/", tarFile, types.CopyToContainerOptions{AllowOverwriteDirWithFile: true}); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error copying to container", err)
    }
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    execCommand, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, container.ID, types.ExecConfig{AttachStdin: true, AttachStderr: true, AttachStdout: true, Cmd: []string{"psql", "-U postgres -f /home/test.sql"}})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("exec err is", err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerExecStart(ctx, execCommand.ID, types.ExecStartCheck{}); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Err Start", err)
    }

    return container.ID
}
```

When I try to do this from CLI, I can run that file and verify that the DB is created. However, programmatically it does not work, and I do not see any errors returned.

The goal is for this to be a library I can reference to spin up a container, import data, and used for integration tests. I am currently calling it from a basic client locally, using `go run main.go` I am working on macOS Monterey v12.4

Comment: Please provide some more information like the `cli.Container...` commands. It is very intransparent what they actually do.

Comment: Furthermore, please define where you exactly run your go program.

Comment: Updated the main post with more code, and defined where and how I run it.

Comment: Can you publish a port from the container, and then connect to it using an ordinary database client library?